# php laravel eloquent like generic typehint

Tags: php, generics, type-hinting

```
class QueryBuilder {
   public function get(): SalesforceObject[] {
      ...
   }
}

class SalesforceObject {
   public function query(): QueryBuilder {
       return new QueryBuilder();
   }
}

class SalesforceAccount extends SalesforceObject {
    public string $Id;
    public string $Name;
}


$accounts = SalesforceAccount::query()->get();

foreach($accounts as $account) {
   $account-> ...
}
```

I would like to get autocompletion in my IDE for the properties of $account without having to add a docblock inside the foreach.

Is there some way to define on the SalesforceAccount class that ->get() of the QueryBuilder class will return SalesforceAccount[] ?

I use eloquent in laravel and there it uses the same architecture and I have autocompletion, so I guess there should be some way with phpdocs to achieve this.

The only way I see to do it natively would be to define a dedicated class that extends QueryBuilder and is only used for SalesforceAccount so I can set return value typehint. However I would like to avoid the need to add a separate query builder class for each object class.

Comment: Use some IDE instruments like Laravel Idea or Laravel IDE Helper, they can generate all hints for editor

Comment: @lezhni they only work with default laravel classes and not with the custom code that I have

Comment: Why are you not using default models?

Comment: Because it is not a model/DB table. It is an independent class that has nothing to do with actual eloquent or databases. It is a wrapper syntax for the salesforce API that I built very similar to what eloquent looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
class QueryBuilder {
    /**
     * @returns SalesforceObject[]
     */
    public function get() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This should work